# Data breakpoints in Qt/C++/OSX: not working?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, debugging, gdb

I have a bug in my code that I am at a loss to track down - it changes the value of a certain memory location.

The code is relatively complex - it is a simulation of a computer system and the subsystem that is breaking is memory management.

The code is C++ and has been built with Qt Creator. I have slapped a data breakpoint on the memory location that is causing the problem (this varies from run to run, but once the code has started is fixed) but while I can see, using static breakpoints, that the value is changing, no break occurs when the memory point being watched is being written to.

The code has many threads of execution running concurrently - could that be an issue?

This is on OSX and is Qt Creator 3.5.1. Though I know the underlying debug mechanism is provided by GDB.

Comment: Could be anything IMO: any part of the code not correctly built (happens to me several times), access to a wrong location of memory (if within you heap, it just make the software to crash further "randomly"), .. I found the debugger quite useless to found memory issues.

Comment: Qt Creator has poor debug mechanism. So people went for other debugers such as VC++ debuger to debug code efficiently.

Comment: I don't think this is a random/corruption issue, it's bad logic design (in my code): the bug does not crash the system, it merely means it doesn't work properly/as expected.

Comment: "Though I know the underlying debug mechanism is provided by GDB.” - On OS X that’d be lldb these days, unless you installed gdb manually.

Comment: I'd suggest to first use the existing tools to find the culprit that overwrites random memory: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2124/_index.html